# High current draw through DC-DC boost circuit

Tags: arduino, atmega, dc-dc-converter

I currently have a simple circuit below which works fine but I am confused with the readings I am getting for when the Atmega1284P is put to sleep.

When it is operating I get a current draw of around 18-20mA. When it goes to sleep with everything disabled. Ie BOD, Timers etc. it is still drawing around 10mA. The atmega should only be drawing a few 100uA when asleep.

I just wanted to check if what I am seeing is correct as I guess the boosting circuit will need to use power to keep the Atmega powered in sleep mode. My next design will power the Atmega directly from the Lipo battery but I would like to learn from this.

I am measuring the current at TP1.

So the question is; if the Atmega1284 is using around 250uA should I be seeing ~10mA of current draw at TP1 because of the dc-dc boost converter circuit?

Thanks guys!

[image]

Comment: Not a single question mark and lots of hand-waving. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean. I have clarified the question.

Comment: You can easily answer the question yourself by just applying an external 5 V at PWR_FLAG. Maybe you will have to disconnect the boost converter output. Now it can be either circuit. If the boost converter is working as expected then it does not consume 10 mA.

Comment: No, the current should not be that high. If this is the whole schematic, then something is definitely wrong. The datasheet for the LM2623 says the quiescent current in operating mode is under 110 uA. Maybe you are not really putting the processor into the low-power mode you expect. Or maybe there is a problem with the application circuit or a defective part.

Comment: Is the programmer connected to the circuit during all of this?

Comment: Nope. I measured all programmers etc disconnected.

Comment: What current do you see if you measure between D2 and U3? Also, what exact diode is D2? An inappropriate choice for D2 may have significant consequences for the boost converter efficiency.

Comment: One way or another, you have to determine if the current is going into the regulator or the processor. One very simple way to do it is to just remove the processor and remeasure the current. If it drops to 100 uA or something, then you know `the processor is the culprit. Another way is to remove or disconnect the regulator and power the board from a bench supply. Have fun.

Comment: In the next design, consider installing 0-Ohm resistors in all locations where you might need to measure current later.

Comment: (experiment 1) Power the microcontroller directly with +5V without the boost converter, and measure the current.  (experiment 2) Temporarily remove the microcontroller from the circuit and measure the current.  (comment) I wouldn't be surprised if the boost converter draws 10mA in this situation.  It's switching, it isn't disabled.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, it is a low-quiescent-current converter. I think it goes into a skip pulse mode at low load. It is possible that the OP made a mistake in component selection or something like that. But if done correctly, the quiescent current of the regulator should be less than 110 uA (per data sheet).

Comment: My bet is that the code which is supposed to put the processor to sleep is not working right. Maybe it is getting hung up before it enters sleep mode. Something like that.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will make some measuements later on today and report back. @mkeith I use the LowPower library to put it into sleep mode so I'm pretty sure it is working ok but I will check it thanks.